# Find 2 people with most common hobbies

Tags: python

```
def find_two_people_with_most_common_hobbies(data: str) -> tuple:
    """
    Find a pair of people who have the highest ratio of common to different hobbies.

    Common hobbies are the ones that both people have.
    Different hobbies are the ones that only one person has.

    Example:
    John has:
        running
        walking
    Mary has:
        dancing
        running
    Nora has:
        running
        singing
        dancing

    Pairs and corresponding common and different hobbies; ratio
    John and Mary; common: running; diff: walking, dancing; ratio: 1/2
    John and Nora; common: running; diff: walking, singing, dancing; ratio: 1/3
    Mary and Nora; common: running, dancing; diff: singing; ratio: 2/1

    So the best result is Mary and Nora. It doesn't matter in which order the names are returned.

    If multiple pairs have the same best ratio, it doesn't matter which pair is returned.

    The exception is when multiple pairs share all of their hobbies, in which case the pair with
    the most shared hobbies is returned.

    A pair with only common hobbies is better than any other pair with at least 1 different hobby.

    Example:
    John has:
        running
        walking
    Mary has:
        running
        walking
    Nora has:
        running
    Oprah has:
        running
    Albert has:
        tennis
        basketball
        football
    Xena has:
        tennis
        basketball
        football
        dancing

    John and Mary have 2 common, 0 different. Ratio 2/0
    Nora and Mary (also Nora and John, Oprah and John, Oprah and Mary) have 1 common, 1 different. Ratio 1/1
    Nora and Oprah have 1 common, 0 different. Ratio 1/0
    Albert and Xena have 3 common, 1 different. Ratio 3/1

    In that case the best pair is John and Mary. If the number of different hobbies is 0,
    then this is better than any pair with at least 1 different hobby.
    Out of the pairs with 0 different hobbies, the one with the highest number
    of common hobbies is the best.
    If there are multiple pairs with the highes number of common hobbies,
    any pair (and in any order) is accepted.

    If there are less than 2 people in the input, return None.
    """
    d = {}
    for v in data.split('\n'):
        k, v = v.split(':')
        if k in d:
            d[k].append(v)
        else:
            d[k] = [v]

    for k1, v1 in d.items():
        for k2, v2 in d.items():
            if k1 != k2:
                for v in v1:
                    if v not in v2:
                        break
                else:
                    return k1, k2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample_data = """Jack:crafting\nPeter:hiking\nWendy:gaming\nMonica:tennis\nChris:origami\nSophie:sport\nMonica:design\nCarmen:sport\nChris:sport\nMonica:skateboarding\nCarmen:cooking\nWendy:photography\nMonica:tennis\nCooper:yoga\nWendy:sport\nCooper:movies\nMonica:theatre\nCooper:yoga\nChris:gaming\nMolly:fishing\nJack:skateboarding\nWendy:fishing\nJack:drawing\nMonica:baking\nSophie:baking\nAlfred:driving\nAlfred:shopping\nAlfred:crafting\nJack:drawing\nCarmen:shopping\nCarmen:driving\nPeter:drawing\nCarmen:shopping\nWendy:fitness\nAlfred:travel\nJack:origami\nSophie:design\nJack:pets\nCarmen:dance\nAlfred:baking\nSophie:sport\nPeter:gaming\nJack:skateboarding\nCooper:football\nAlfred:sport\nCooper:fitness\nChris:yoga\nWendy:football\nMolly:design\nJack:hiking\nMonica:pets\nCarmen:photography\nJack:baking\nPeter:driving\nChris:driving\nCarmen:driving\nPeter:theatre\nMolly:hiking\nWendy:puzzles\nJack:crafting\nPeter:photography\nCarmen:theatre\nSophie:crafting\nCarmen:cooking\nAlfred:gaming\nPeter:theatre\nCooper:hiking\nChris:football\nChris:pets\nJack:football\nMonica:skateboarding\nChris:driving\nCarmen:pets\nCooper:gaming\nChris:hiking\nJack:cooking\nPeter:fishing\nJack:gaming\nPeter:origami\nCarmen:movies\nSophie:driving\nJack:sport\nCarmen:theatre\nWendy:shopping\nCarmen:pets\nWendy:gaming\nSophie:football\nWendy:theatre\nCarmen:football\nMolly:theatre\nPeter:theatre\nMonica:flowers\nMolly:skateboarding\nPeter:driving\nSophie:travel\nMonica:photography\nCooper:cooking\nJack:fitness\nPeter:cooking\nChris:gaming"""
    dic = create_dictionary(sample_data)
    data = "John:running\nMary:running\nJohn:dancing\nJack:dancing\nJack:painting\nSmith:painting"
    hobbies = ["running", "dancing"]
```

I tried this but got the following errors: [image]

Comment: What is `create_dictionary`? where is the actual comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two classes for this task, one for person and other for person pair. And person class should not let you create new person with same name but return an instance of existed one. Then after passing data string and creating all persons it's needed to create all possible pairs which are all permutations of persons. In class person pair should be described methods for comparison (**gt**, **lt**) which will allow to find best pair with max method on list of pairs.

Here is my realization:

```
from itertools import permutations


class PersonHobby:
    _persons = dict()

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        name = args[0]
        if name in cls._persons:
            return cls._persons[name]
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        cls._persons[name] = instance
        return instance

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hobby = []

    def add_hobby(self, hobby):
        self.hobby.append(hobby)

    @classmethod
    def get_all_persons(cls):
        return cls._persons.values()

    @classmethod
    def reset_persons(cls):
        cls._persons = dict()
    

class PersonPair:
    def __init__(self, person1, person2):
        self.person1 = person1
        self.person2 = person2
    
    def get_common_hobbies_amount(self):
        person_1_hobbies = set(self.person1.hobby)
        person_2_hobbies = set(self.person2.hobby)
        return len(person_1_hobbies.intersection(person_2_hobbies))

    def get_different_hobbies_amount(self):
        person_1_hobbies = set(self.person1.hobby)
        person_2_hobbies = set(self.person2.hobby)
        return len(person_1_hobbies.symmetric_difference(person_2_hobbies))

    def __gt__(self, other):
        amount_common = self.get_common_hobbies_amount()
        amount_diff = self.get_different_hobbies_amount()

        amount_common_other = other.get_common_hobbies_amount()
        amount_diff_other = other.get_different_hobbies_amount()

        if amount_diff_other != 1 and amount_diff == 0:
            return True
        
        if amount_diff_other == 0 and amount_diff != 0:
            return False

        if amount_diff_other == 0 and amount_diff == 0:
            return amount_common > amount_common_other
        
        return (amount_common 
                / amount_diff) > (amount_common_other 
                                  / amount_diff_other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        amount_common = self.get_common_hobbies_amount()
        amount_diff = self.get_different_hobbies_amount()

        amount_common_other = other.get_common_hobbies_amount()
        amount_diff_other = other.get_different_hobbies_amount()

        if amount_diff_other != 1 and amount_diff == 0:
            return False
        
        if amount_diff_other == 0 and amount_diff != 0:
            return True

        if amount_diff_other == 0 and amount_diff == 0:
            return amount_common > amount_common_other
        
        return (amount_common 
                / amount_diff) < (amount_common_other 
                                  / amount_diff_other)


def find_two_people_with_most_common_hobbies(data: str) -> tuple:
    PersonHobby.reset_persons()
    lines = data.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        name, hobby = line.split(':')
        person = PersonHobby(name)
        person.add_hobby(hobby)
    persons = PersonHobby.get_all_persons()
    if len(persons) < 2:
        return None
    all_pairs = permutations(persons, 2)
    pairs = []
    for pair in all_pairs:
        pairs.append(PersonPair(pair[0], pair[1]))

    best_pair = max(pairs)
    return (best_pair.person1.name, best_pair.person2.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample_data_2 = """John:running\nJohn:walking\nMary:dancing\nMary:running\nNora:running\nNora:singing\nNora:dancing"""
    print(find_two_people_with_most_common_hobbies(sample_data_2)) #('John', 'Mary')
```